# Don't understand sintaxis using ? in textAppearance

Tags: android, android-studio, android-theme, android-styles

I have been learning about textAppearance attribute and I don't understand the sintaxis that uses ?.
I perfectly understand when we use this sintaxis: 
**android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Headline"**

But I don't understand when we use this sintaxis: 
**?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge**

What are the differences between these two ways of defining the textAppearance?

Using @android/style is understandable because we reference a style resource, but why is there this other way of referencing a style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#ReferencesToThemeAttributes):

> A style attribute resource allows you to reference the value of an attribute in the currently-applied theme. Referencing a style attribute allows you to customize the look of UI elements by styling them to match standard variations supplied by the current theme, instead of supplying a hard-coded value. Referencing a style attribute essentially says, **"use the style that is defined by this attribute, in the current theme."**
>
> To reference a style attribute, the name syntax is almost identical to the normal resource format, but instead of the at-symbol (`@`), use a question-mark (`?`), and the resource type portion is optional.

You can use a **style** like:

```
android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1"
```

In this way you are using:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1" parent=".....">
  ...
</style>
```

You can use an **attribute** defined in your **app theme**:

```
 android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle1"
```

In your app theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
   <item name="textAppearanceSubtitle1">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1</item>
</style>
```

The same behavior is used for other resources. For example the colors:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
   <item name="colorPrimary">@color/....</item>
</style>
```

In a view you can use:

```
app:backgroundTint="?attr/colorPrimary"
```